# How to detect if which one of the back or forward button of the browser was pressed?

Tags: javascript

Scoured SO and the net to find a solution but ended up with almost all answers pointing to the same solutions:

`TYPE_BACK_FORWARD` of performance or `performancenavigationtiming` which all just pertain to whether you click either back or forward.

This is not my goal since I was hoping to determine if it was the back or forward button that was pressed.

Sorry for the newbie question I was hoping there was a simple straightforward function in JavaScript that could do this since it's simple enough, not sure why they made it so hard to find this simple function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To clarify: do you want to identify that the user is pressing either the back or the forward button in their browser while viewing the page that your JS is on? Or do you want to be able to identify whether they arrived at the page your JS is on by pressing either the back or the forward button of the browser?

Comment: the first, whether they pressed the back or the forward button, I know after researching online that there is a function to detect what the source of the trigger to land on a webpage is, but it does not differentiate between the back and forward button.. not that..